# Force encode/databases to use asyncpg instead of psycopg2

Tags: python, database, postgresql, fastapi, asyncpg

Recently, I am trying to use encode/databases packages with my postgres db. I have done all correctly. But when I go to run it with uvicorn, I see that it shows me that psycopg2 is not installed. I do not wan to use psycopg2. So, I restated all and run `databases[postgresql]` instead of `databases` only. I also installed `asyncpg`. But I am still seeing the same err. **I was also doing everything in a virtual environment.** My code is attached below:

```
import databases, sqlalchemy, asyncpg
from fastapi import FastAPI

#POSTGRES DATABASE
DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://xxxxxxxxxxx" # hidden
database = databases.Database(DATABASE_URL)
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()

users = sqlalchemy.Table(
    "py_users",
    metadata,
    sqlalchemy.Column("id"        , sqlalchemy.String, primary_key=True),
    sqlalchemy.Column("username"  , sqlalchemy.String),
    sqlalchemy.Column("password"  , sqlalchemy.String),
    sqlalchemy.Column("first_name", sqlalchemy.String),
    sqlalchemy.Column("last_name" , sqlalchemy.String),
    sqlalchemy.Column("gender"    , sqlalchemy.CHAR  ),
    sqlalchemy.Column("created_at", sqlalchemy.String),
    sqlalchemy.Column("status"    , sqlalchemy.CHAR  ),
)

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    DATABASE_URL
)
metadata.create_all(engine)

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/users')
def find_all_users():
    return "List All Users"
```

and the traceback is:

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [110] using statreload
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/HelloCoderFastAPITuto/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/subprocess.py", line 61, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/home/runner/HelloCoderFastAPITuto/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/_impl/asyncio.py", line 47, in run
    loop.run_until_complete(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/HelloCoderFastAPITuto/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/_impl/asyncio.py", line 54, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/home/runner/HelloCoderFastAPITuto/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 306, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/home/runner/HelloCoderFastAPITuto/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 23, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/runner/HelloCoderFastAPITuto/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 20, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "./main.py", line 22, in <module>
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 500, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 87, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 778, in dbapi
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

From the above errors I think that the package databases is trying to use psycopg2 instead of asyncpg. And in that case how do I force the databases package to use asyncpg instead of psycopg2. If that is not the case how do I use asyncpg instead of using psycopg2?

Thanks in advance.

**My question may have some mistakes. Please ignore those silly mistakes and just edit the question if you find any mistakes in my question**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in your case SQLAlchemy trying to use **psycopg2**.

See the error:

> opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py

When declaring tables, it is done by SQLAlchemy. But the connections between that, it is done by **asyncpg**.

In the documentation it clearly states

> Driver support is providing using one of **asyncpg**.

So you do not need to worry about that. Encode will use **asyncpg**.

Comment: What is the asynchronous solution for that?

Comment: creating tables asynchronously? Your connections between the Database and your app should be asynchronous. Why do you think there is something wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You need a different connection string for SQLAlchemy.

```py
DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://xxxxxxxxxxx" # database url for databases library
DATABASE_URL_SQLALCHEMY = "postgresql+asyncpg://xxxxxxxxxxx" # database url for SQLAlchemy
```

Also `metadata.create_all(engine)` won't work since that function don’t include an awaitable hook.

Checkout https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html for more information.

Comment: That is the SOLUTION! Thanks!
The only problem in async — database inspection is not supported, unfortunately. Inspection on an AsyncEngine is currently required some tricks, discussed at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/xd3s

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `databases`](https://github.com/encode/databases#installation) clearly states, and I quote:

> Note that if you are using any synchronous SQLAlchemy functions such as `engine.create_all()` or alembic migrations then you still have to install a synchronous DB driver: psycopg2 for PostgreSQL and pymysql for MySQL.

And you have this piece of code inside your program:

```py
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    DATABASE_URL
)
metadata.create_all(engine)
```